# Understanding Material test scene

Tags: materials

Could someone explain to me what the numbers on the floor mean? also maybe any other pertinent info that would be good to know. What should I be looking for?

[image]

Comment: The floor numbers look like a simple [UV Test Grid](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=UV%20test%20grid) for size/positioning reference maybe